# Using Hugo library in app with new gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was trying to use the Hugo plugin for my app.
But whenever I try to upgrade my AGP ( from 3.5.0 to 7.0.2 or higher) and Gradle version(from 5.4.1 to 7.2 and higher) the error comes as

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.jakewharton.hugo'.

> Could not find method debugCompile() for arguments [com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

My app was previously compiled using API 28 and now I am trying to compile it using API 33.
I have followed the steps as mentioned in the Hugo GitHub repository.
My project build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
//        google()
        maven {
          url = uri ("https://maven.google.com")
       }
        maven {
          url = uri ("https://maven.fabric.io/public")
       }
        jcenter()
//        mavenCentral()
  }
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
  classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'// google-services plugin
  classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:3.0.2'
  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
//        google()
      maven {
         url = uri ("https://maven.google.com")// Google's Maven repository
       }
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
       }
      maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io")  }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to update the Gradle version and AGP, but it shows error.

Comment: You dont need to add ` on each line because it makes it difficult to read it, just add ``` (3 times in the beginning) and in the end of your code. I have edited the post, but double check if it's correct